# Php exec() return code is -1 when in a forked process, but 0 in a normal script

Tags: php

I am using exec() inside a a script that runs as a daemon and forks child processes using the pear class Net_Server.

I am getting a strange issue whereby the return code (the third param of of exec) comes back as -1. When I run the command on the command line, or with exec in a normal php script the return code is 0 as it should be. Anyone have any idea why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Comment: Does that code use `pcntl_signal()` by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 pcntl_signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_DFL);
 exec('...');
 pcntl_signal(SIGCHLD, 'whatever it was');
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. The pear class was setting 

pcntl_signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);

Comment: Could you please give a bit more info about the 'whatever it was' part? How do I know what should I put there? Thanks

Comment: @gabo: whatever it was it just that, the problem of the original asker was that something was overriding the default signal handler for `SIGCHLD` with 'something'. The solution for him was going back to the default `SIG_DFL` for what he needed to do, and after that set the signal handler for `SIGCHLD` back to whatever it was overriden with in the first place (likely for a good reason). No way to tell what that was in the code. If you use a specific signal handler instead of the deafult, you most will know what that is in your code unless your using undocumented 3rd party code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is an issue with environment variables. Maybe the thing you are trying to execute is normally in your PATH, but not when you spawn a daemon. Supply the full path to the program.